# Polyfill not applied on imported files

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babel-polyfill

I'm working on a Vue JS project in which I use ES6 syntax. I've added a polyfill by importing '@babel/polyfill' at the top of my app's entry point (main.js), which works for most of my project.

The problem I've now encountered is that the polyfill isn't applied on imported files. So this means that when

- When my ES6 function is imported, the page is rendered correctly in Chrome but not in IE11
- When I directly copy and paste the contents of the imported file (without the export syntax) into my main file, the page is rendered correctly in both browsers.

How do I correctly Polyfill in this situation?

---

### EDIT

: Apparantly this issue had nothing to do with polyfills, but with babel instead. I openend a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016829/webpack-babel-loader-doesnt-transpile-imported-js-files)

Comment: You should import the polyfill before any other files that are dependent to it.

Comment: I've added the polyfill to the top of my main file (first line). Or do you mean that I should import the polyfill in the imported file as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing the polyfills like this then it should work without glitches:

```
// IE11 Polyfil fix
import Es6Promise from 'es6-promise/auto'
require('core-js/fn/object/assign');
import githubFetch from 'whatwg-fetch'

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import { VTooltip } from 'v-tooltip'
import Routes from './routes'
import events from './events'
import auth_mixin from './auth'
import { isAuthenticated, getTokenID, getUserID } from "./auth"
import config from './config'
import axios from 'axios'
import App from './App'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I indeed imported my polyfills like that, but as it turns out, the polyfills weren't causing the issue. I've edited my main post.