# Webpack babel-loader doesn't transpile imported .js files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

My VueJS app doesn't render correctly in IE11 (polyfills are being applied though).

I discovered that this is caused by several JS files I imported into my project, which apparantly aren't transpiled by babel. And indeed, when I manually transpile these files (babel-cli) and import the transpiled version, the problem is resolved.

However, these files should be transpiled by automatically, just like the rest of my project.

How can I solve this issue?

**import example**

```
import depth from '@/functions/depth'
```

*('@' is resolved by webpack. Path is correct)*

**My .babelrc file (originally from vue webpack [boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack))**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime"]
}
```

**webpack config (originally from vue webpack [boilerplate](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack))**

```
 module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
          }, (...)
```

Comment: I suggest to add babel-polyfill into your entry point. Something just like:
    `entry : [
        'babel-polyfill',
        './src/index'
    ],`
...

Comment: @SergeyAvanesyan I have, but makes no difference.

Comment: Which files need to be compiled? Your `include` means it will only compile `src` and `test`, so if they are outside those directories, that is your answer.

Comment: @loganfsmyth '@' points to src. My functions folder is in /src/functions. I guess it's resolved recursively ?

Comment: And they are `.js` files, not `.jsx` files or something? It's really hard to say based on just the information we have. What is `resolve` in this context?